# Background image will not render when hosted

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

I have built a landing page for an external client all is working fine, I have a background image which fits the hole screen, I modified the existing body tag within the bootstrap.css class as follows

```
body {
margin: 0;
background-image: url('/Content/Images/Danone-Background-New.png');
background-size: 1440px 800px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
color: #333333;
background-color: #ffffff;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Again this works perfectly when running locally, I then publish this site to the hosting environment, and when I navigate to the site all the content is displayed minus the background image, so I first assumed I have the wrong path so I checked the body style using firebug and this is what I see

```
body {
background-color: #fff;
color: #333;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

So for first glance I assumed "Oh that's strange it hasn't copied over my body styles!" so I repeat the process again and low and behold the body style remains as above, So i login to the server navigate through the files to the bootstrap.css find the body tag and again it looks as I expected

```
body {
margin: 0;
background-image: url('/Content/Images/Danone-Background-New.png');
background-size: 1440px 800px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
color: #333333;
background-color: #ffffff;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Yet the image does not render.

What is wrong with this? I have tried ctrl f5, looked in the development tool bar checked for any 404 erros nothing displayed ? I'm baffled?!

Link to check www.danoneultimate.com.au

Comment: can you post your link?

Comment: @jmore009 www.danoneultimate.com.au

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` section of your website, you load a different stylesheet.

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=WY2Ybti5pBJYm0QfqiFBL2b5U_cKoeAWQC9DALv4mnw1" rel="stylesheet">
```

Change it so that it loads bootstrap.css:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I am using the bundle config and as mentioned below the only styles inside the bundle config are bootstrap.css and site.css

Answer (score -2):

You have edited bootstrap.css but you're loading bootstrap.min.css.

Your code works just fine :)

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Really? http://www.danoneultimate.com.au/Content/css?v=WY2Ybti5pBJYm0QfqiFBL2b5U_cKoeAWQC9DALv4mnw1 This shows minified version of bootstrap.
And if i replace it with bootstrap.css it shows your background image.

Comment: This was the first thing I checked, inside the bundle config I have bootstrap.css and site.css